# Finding mutual friends for a huge dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, graph, bigdata

where I have a huge data set of the form
userId follows userId

1 -> 2 (i.e) 1 follows 2

1 -> 3

3 -> 5

2 -> 3

The idea is I want to find out how many common followers two people have 
For example in the above case the number of mutual followers between user 1 and user 2 is 1, since (user 1 and user 2 both follow user 3)

Whats the best way to implement it for a huge dataset. Simple collecting by user id, and then performing a join wouldn't work. I am thinking of using some graph approaches.

Comment: If this is an interview question, then you probably should finish by yourself. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have a graph represented as adjacency list. And you have an operation on this graph `get a list of the neighbors of a given vertex`. Vertex P1 is first person, vertex P2 - second person. Now you can do next (should use a hash set for fast intersection):

```
p1_follows = HashSet(neighbors(P1))
p2_follows = neighbors(P2);
mutual_followers = p1_follows.intersect(p2_follows)
```

If you use use [GraphFrame](https://graphframes.github.io), you can go with [Motif finding](https://graphframes.github.io/user-guide.html#motif-finding) - here is an example [Motif Finding: Counting Mutual Friends](https://www.coursera.org/learn/big-data-analysis/lecture/eTXJJ/motif-finding-counting-mutual-friends).